# Will UDP socket pool improve datagram delivery successful rate and be more efficient?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, udp, solaris

I am developing a UDP client module in Solaris using C, and there are 2 design modules:

(1) Create a socket, and send all messages through this socket. The receive thread only call `recvfrom` on this socket.

(2) Create a group of sockets. When sending message, select a socket randomly from the socket pool. The receive thread needs to call `poll` or `select` on a group of sockets.

When the throughput is low, I think the first design module is OK.

If the throughput is high, I am wondering whether the second design module can be better? 
Because it will dispatch messages to a group of sockets, and this maybe improve UDP datagram delivery successful rate and more efficient.

Comment: What throughput are you expecting? Is this running at say, 10Mb, 100Mb, 1Gb, 10Gb or 100Gb? And in addition, what CPU and architecture does your server have? How many cores and how fast are the cores? I would like to answer but it depends to heavily on these questions.

Answer (score 1):

There's still only one network. You can have as many sockets, threads, whatever, as you like. The rate-determining step is the network. There is no point to this.

Answer (score 0):

The question here primarily depends on how parallel the computer is (number of cores) and how parallel the algorithm is. Most likely your CPU cores are vastly faster than the network connection anyway and even one of them could easily overwhelm the connection. Thus on a typical system option (1) will give significantly better performance and lower drop rates.

This is because there is a significant overhead to using a UDP port on several threads or processes due to the internal locking the OS has to do to ensure the packets' contents are not multiplexed and corrupted, this causes a significant performance loss and significantly increased chance of packet loss where the kernel gives up waiting for other threads and just throws your pending packets away.

In the extreme case where your cores are very slow and your connection extremely fast (say a 500 core super computer with a 10 - 100Gbit fibre connection) option two could become more feasible, the locking would be less likely as the connection would be fast enough to keep many cores busy without them tripping over each other and locking often, this will -not- increase reliability (and may slightly decrease it) but might increase throughput depending on your architecture.

Overall in nearly every case I would suggest option 1, but if you really do have an extreme throughput situation you should look into other methods, however if you are writing software for this kind of system you would probably benefit from some more general training in massively parallel systems.

I hope this helps, if you have any queries please leave a comment.

Comment: Since when does a kernel 'give up waiting for other threads and throw your ***outbound*** packets away'?

Comment: @EJP Admittedly I have not looked at the sources of Solaris so cannot tell you what it will do but this is absolutely conforming, UDP packets can be thrown away by the kernel in a BSD style sockets implementation if the network interface is too busy to process them, otherwise the kernel would need an infinite queue of pending packets in the case of a CPU sending packets faster than the network interface can transmit them. (of course it is also allowed to make the process block, but this is harder for the OS to predict so often the throwing away method is used.)

Comment: Whoever gave the down-vote, please give me an opportunity to explain or edit my answer before voting, otherwise I am unable to help address your qualm and do not know what is wrong with the answer.

Comment: @EJP For example have a look in the Linux kernel's UDP multi-cast support, that can drop outbound UDP packets under some circumstances. In addition if the kernel uses rate limiting for UDP which is an available and often used option that will also cause it to sometimes drop UDP packets.

Comment: The kernel has a socket send buffer per TCP or UDP socket, whose size is given by the socket option SO_SNDBUF, and it has the ability to block the sender while it's full. The only two permissible behaviours for send() when the socket send buffer is full are (1) block or (2) return -1/EAGAIN in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP Hmn, What about this man page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/send "ENOBUFS
    The output queue for a network interface was full. This generally indicates that the interface has stopped sending, but may be caused by transient congestion. (Normally, this does not occur in Linux. Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows.)" That would appear to indicate that POSIX allows silent drops in the case of a full network buffer. I realise the UDP buffer will not drop packets but the actual network buffer -can-. That appears to be an allowed if the socket buffer is full or not.

Comment: @EJP Again I yield that I have not read the Solaris kernel so cannot promise you it's particular behaviour but POSIX certainly allows silent drops from a send.